# SQL Concat int to string in mariadb

Tags: sql, casting, mariadb, concatenation

Iam working in XAMP on a local database Mariadb and want to add/concat a word to an int
This is my query

```
Select 'id:' + cast(Cid as varchar) from table where Cid is 3747;
```

The result should be id:3747

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: 1) `where Cid = 3747`

Comment: 2) `concat('id: ', cast(Cid as varchar(11)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CONCAT.
And the `IS` operator is only used for [NOT] NULL.
F.e. `select col from tbl where col IS NOT NULL`

```
select concat('id:', Cid) as result
from table 
where Cid = 3747
```

But you could use `IN` also

```
select concat('id:', Cid) as result
from table 
where Cid in (3747)
```